# p-value comparison

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, p-value

Is it possible to compare two p-values? Suppose for a test with significance level 0.05, I get p = 0.06, and for another test with similar data, I get p = 0.20. What can I say if I want to make comments about these two values other than hypothesis acceptance or rejection?

Comment: What do you mean by compare p-values? Like combining them? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combining-p-values

Comment: Not exactly combining. I have done two chi-square tests; for one, I got p = 0.06 and for another, I got p = 0.20. My significance level is 0.05. So, in both cases, my conclusion will be "fail to reject the null hypothesis." But my question is, since 0.06 is closer to 0.05 and 0.20 is far away, can I say something based on the relative distance from the significance level? @SextusEmpiricus

Comment: It means that in the one test you observed a stronger effect relative to the error of the test. This was either because you observed a stronger effect, had less noisy observations, or a larger sample. That's how you can compare the results. Because both are above the standard that you have set (or someone else did that for you) both results are not statistically significant enough for them to be relevant. It means that in both cases the data do not give a strong indication that the null hypothesis is false or that the true effect is far from the null hypothesis.

Comment: Are these tests of the same hypothesis or tests of different hypotheses?

Comment: Thank you! These tests are for the same hypothesis. For sample size 836, p= 0.056, and for sample size 784, it's 0.2.

Comment: No, you should do a homogeneity test (usually) to answer such questions.

Comment: @statm if these are tests of the same hypothesis, then I do not understand what the point is of the comparison. Say we have a coin and want to test whether it is unfair $p_{heads} \neq 0.5$. Some person flips the coin 836 times and registers 440 heads (52.6% of the time), another person flips the coin 784 times and registers 404 heads (51.5% of the time). In the end they are the same coin. What is the point of comparing these two results? ...

Comment: ... One way of comparison that I can imagine is a test for goodness of fit (testing whether the model itselve is correct). For example when we have many such p-values and observe a pattern that would not correspond with an alternative hypothesis. But, with only two values this test is not so easily made.

Comment: You ask if it's *possible* to compare them. Clearly so, since you can easily answer a question of the form "is p1 bigger or smaller than p2?". The better question is whether that makes any sense at all to do (to which the answer is almost always "no"). Why would you do this in the first place? What problem do you think it solves / what question do you think it would provide an answer to? Explaining that might lead to much better advice beyond "don't compare p-values".

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say more than whether one test was significant or not. Note that [the difference between "significant" and "not significant” is not itself statistically significant" (Gelman & Stern, 2006)](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313006X152649), ungated version [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/signif4.pdf). If you want to "compare two tests", you will need to test the difference (or some other function) of the test statistics, and probably be *very* careful about the null distribution.